# PageInspector doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am running Visual Studio 2013 with Update 5. I am getting the following error in the Page Inspector browser window:

> Page Inspector's Runtime must be registered in root web.config.

Here's my relevant Web.Config settings:

```html
  <appSettings>
    <add key="vs:enableBrowserLink" value="true" />
    <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Enabled"/>
    <add key="VisualStudioDesignTime:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ClearPluginsShadowDirectoryOnStartup" value="False" />
    <!-- By default this setting should always be set to "False" (only for advanced users)-->
```

The provided link gave me an out of date page describing describing the fix. It said to reinstall  Microsoft Web Tooling Extensions – Visual Studio 2012. Obviously, I'm not running VS 2012 and I couldn't find the VS 2013 version.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the web tools for visual studio 2013. Goto control panel->Programs and Features. Select Visual Studio 2013 and click Modify. Once the installer  loads click Modify and ensure that Microsoft Web Developer Tools is selected.